# mPDF error when table too large for page

Tags: phpexcel, mpdf

Using the following PHP code:

```
$pdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');  //have tried several of the formats
$pdf->WriteHTML($content,2);
$pdf->Output();
```

where $content is a very plain html table

As long as the number of rows in the table are less than one page, the PDF is generated without errors.  If I add one or more rows to the html I get the PHP warnings:

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: mpdf/mpdf.php
Line Number: 11043
```

repeated many, many times.  With mPDF error notices turned on I get

```
mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

I tried suppressing the warnings using the code in [Can't get rid of PHP notices in mPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067872/php-mpdf-cant-get-rid-of-notices)

This sort of worked, but the force-downloaded PDF has the following quirk:

```
first page: blank
2nd page:  table header only
3rd to next to last pages:  header and 1 row of data
last page:  header + full page of data
```

This is the 3rd PDF from PHP library I've tried to use with my CodeIgniter framework, so I'm extremely frustrated at this point.

PHPExcel (which I'm using to give my client Excel download data option) works awesome for formatting Excel spreadsheets, but the output to PDF is hideous no matter what options I throw at it (mainly, it puts a outline around each cell with a HUGE padding)

ezPDF/PHP-PDF (per http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrate-ezpdf-a-k-a-pdf-php-into-codeigniter-framework) worked awesome.  Except I couldn't get it to work with the client's logo that they were adamant about showing at the top of the PDF.

I guess I'm going to try domPDF next.

Comment: Have you tried working with the latest develop branch of PHPExcel from github that no longer uses tcPDF as a built-in PDF renderer, but provides wrappers for your choice of mPDF, DomPDF or tcPDF?

Comment: I saw that that functionality was slated for next release, but hadn't looked in the development branch to see if it had been implemented yet, I'll check it out, as that would be my preferred route since I'm already using PHPExcel for the spreadsheet downloads.  I got domPDF working last night wit all of the data and it shows the logo.  I still need to format it to fit the pages size though.  Thanks for the suggestion Mark.