# Opencart: convert .tpl 2 .pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, export, opencart

I need to provide the user a way to download the confirmation view as a PDF,

Does Opencart provide a easy way to export a .tpl as .pdf? even with some tweaking?

Please note: It's for the opencart framework but it's not to print a order preview, its a custom page,

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there is no concrete answer for You, this question includes a solution that I have used for printing the `.tpl` invoices into `.pdf` files: [Can't get rid of PHP notices in mPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067872/php-mpdf-cant-get-rid-of-notices)

Comment: Acepted cause is right, there is not a right answer; thanks for your suggestion, I ended up using dompdf :)