# MPDF not generating anything on external server

Tags: php, mpdf

I've generated a beautiful HTML invoice with MPDF, but when I placed it on the server it isn't showing anything.

The logs show the following for local (here the generation works):

http://pastebin.com/n3xJujBH

The logs show the following when generating on the server (here it shows an empty HTML page on generation, not PDF):

http://pastebin.com/HDeSPHse

The following code is used to generate the PDF in Codeigniter:

```
private function _gen_pdf($html,$paper='A4')
{
    $this->load->library('mpdf53/mpdf');

    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8',$paper);
    $mpdf->debug = true;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

The HTML created is following: http://pastebin.com/b3hFNbT8

Something to note is that, if I put only "test" in `$html`, it won't generate either.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `Undefined index: BODY` etc in your logs makes it look like it is looking for an HTML document encoded into an array, and not finding anything. Check to ensure this (`$html` I expect) is not empty, and is a valid document (run it through the W3C validator online).

Comment: Also, do you have any PHP version/extension differences between the two environments?

Comment: @halfer i've just runned the w3c validator, removed 13 errors and it's now a html save and correct document. Sadly no results, local still works fine and only no happens nothing. On my local machine the generation works on php 5.3.20 and 5.4.10. The External is php 5.3.15 so i think that won't be a problem. 

Finally i like to note that i can insert the writeHTML("Hello world") and it won't write either... Are there any  server side dependencies?

Comment: I've no idea whether it has dependencies, I haven't used it. Does turning off `debug` mode help at all?

Comment: No debug mode doesn't have any effect at all.

Comment: Maybe the notices are being rendered too, and are corrupting the delivered PDF? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067872/php-mpdf-cant-get-rid-of-notices) or use the `@` operator on the constructor call and/and `WriteHTML` and/or `Output`.

Comment: I tried the @, but it won't help.. Neither does the code in the other post. I found out , that i get a good generated empty PDF if i remove the writeHTML on the external server. But that doesn't help a lot i think..

Comment: Righto, I am out of ideas then sadly. You may need to do some on-server debugging, or perhaps turn up your log levels to see if there's something you've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was switching to DomPDF. I never got in functioning on the external parallels server and will probably never know why..

Comment: This happens mostly when your remote/live php version is not compiled with mbstring support. On top of that the mPDF's newer versions are using @mb_regex_encoding() throughout its code hiding error reporting. It took me a while to fix it. Hope this help others!

Answer (score 1):

This got me pass the obstacle

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/tmp']);
```

Create custom (this can be anything) directory if it tells some permission error on the live server like on aws ubuntu instance etc...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

I tried this code and it gave me the issue due to which mpdf was not working.

```
<?php

    // Require composer autoload
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    try {
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $mpdf->debug = true;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML("Hello World");
        $mpdf->Output();
    } catch (\Mpdf\MpdfException $e) { // Note: safer fully qualified exception 
                                       //       name used for catch
        // Process the exception, log, print etc.
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

In my case i had to make the folder where i had kept my files writable.